# Cast away volatile in plain old C

Tags: c, casting

I'm looking for a way to only cast away volatility, without casting away the underlying type.  I know about `const_cast` in C++, and I'm wondering if there is any equivalent way to do this in plain old C.

The problem is we've got some shared memory databases that are accessed through volatile pointers, and also a B-tree library that works with non-volatile pointers.  (The tree will be locked during a find so it is fine for the compiler to not worry about the volatility within the B-tree library).

We also have a load of auto-generated code that links up the two, and casts away the volatile from the pointer.  Unfortunately, today someone had defined the tree nodes using the wrong structure in the database, and that auto-generated cast completely hid the problem from the compiler.

Comment: The standard C cast does perform cv-casting as well as everything else.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think that's exactly the point. `Foo volatile*` is apparently supposed to be castable to `Foo*` but not to `Bar*`.

Comment: If you are using GCC, it is possible that you could do this with a few compiler extensions...

Comment: @bitmask: `Foo*` *isn't* castable to `Bar*` -- it's just that the compiler doesn't stop you :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes but ideally you would want to have a type safe cast which allows you to get away with removing (or adding) `cv` qualifiers. See my answer, that's how I understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky but you can get the preprocessor to help you here, if you only want to convert from pointer types to pointer types.

```
#define cv_cast(TYPE,expr) (*((TYPE)(expr)) = *(expr),(TYPE)(expr))
```

> Usage:
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>   float f;
> } Foo;
>
> typedef struct {
>   char b;
> } Bar;
>
> void somefunction(void) {
>   Foo f; Bar b;
>   Foo volatile* foov = &f;
>   Foo* foo = 0;
>   Bar* bar = &b;
>   foo = cv_cast(Foo*,foov); // legal (no error, no warning)
>   foov = cv_cast(Foo*,foo); // legal (no error, no warning)
>   foo = cv_cast(Foo*,bar); // illegal (an error)
> }
> ```

The basic trick here is that we force an assignment from `Bar` to `Foo` in a `cv_cast` from `Bar*` to `Foo*`. This is done in the part after the `,`. It will trigger an error if and only if you are casting incompatible pointer types.

However, note that `cv_cast`ing pointers that point to invalid locations (e.g. `NULL`) will cause segfaults.

---

Note: For reference (in the comments) this post used a helper function `nullfn` previously that is not necessary. You can look it up in the history if you're interested.

Comment: I like the idea but we have a slight problem in that we write mostly custom stuff with a support contract, rather than boxed software.  So we ship code with debug symbols in, and with optimisation disabled.  So I'm a bit reticent to add a null function call into the database finds.

Comment: NB if this was ever likely to cause a problem in production I'd take the hit on performance.  But in reality if the coder gets this wrong, it trashes the shared memory database very quickly and obviously during early development.  It just takes an hour of head scratching to work out how the corruption started!

Comment: @asc99c: There is another option, that I tried to hint in the answer. If you do not activate the `unused-value` (which is activated by `-Wextra`) warning you can do this much easier without the call `nullfn` just replace the define with the code I provided in "2.". It works just as well. The only reason for the call to `nullfn` is to keep the compiler from issuing an `unused-value` warning.

Comment: @asc99c: Okay, apparently I missed something. The beauty is that that warning only comes when you would have an error anyway! So, you don't need the function call at all. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, thanks for the hint. Must have introduced the extra brace when copying it here. Fixed.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you are trying to do. However, it seems your code contains the very bug you are trying to protect against, plus a few more. If I got it right, essentially this is what the code does: `(*(Foo*)foov) = *foov, (Foo*)foov;`. Simplified this is the same as `(*(Foo*)foov) = (Foo*)foov;`. First bug: assign the address of foov to the memory location that foov points at. Other bugs: 2 unintentional, unwanted side effects by accessing a volatile. Since the code is meant to deal with volatile in particular, you should never do that.

Comment: @Lundin: No it is a comma expression, which means if you have `(a,b)`, it means that `a` will be evaluated, then `b` will be evaluated and the result of the evaluation of `b` will be the value of `(a,b)`. What I do with the `a` part makes sure that the type of `expr` can be assigned to a `TYPE`. I give you the side effects due to accessing a volatile, though.

Comment: @bitmask I know what the comma operator does, read my comment again. Because the right-hand side is the one that ends up as result of it, you have a bug, as shown in my comment.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm sorry, but I don't see your concern. I believe you misread the braces. Keep in mind that the `,` has the lowest possible precedence. Your "Simplified this is the same as" is not correct, as the assignment binds stronger than the comma. The entire left side of the comma is `*((TYPE)(expr)) = *(expr)`. The result of this expression is discarded by the comma operator and the complete expression will have the value of the part right of the comma, which is `(TYPE)(expr)`. Again, the part left of the comma is only to trigger compiler errors, its result will never be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't really have much in the way of type safety, there is nothing in the standard that will help spotting such bugs at compile-time. Any explicit typecast might cast away the type entirely and leave you with undefined behavior.

If you are afraid that such typecasts may appear, I suppose you could always make some sort of macro to make such errors harder to write.

```
#define PTR_CONST_CAST(type, ptr) ((type*)ptr)

volatile int* const ptr_original;
int* ptr_new;

ptr_new = PTR_CONST_CAST(int, ptr_original); 
/* Note: here I am casting away volatile and const because... */
```

This macro doesn't add any type safety at all. But at least it makes the programmer aware of the possibly dangerous typecast, hopefully causing them to think twice before writing a bug. A comment expressing why it is safe to do so in the specific case, is also good practice.

But the only real serious way to weed out all incorrect casts is first to tune up compiler warnings to max. Compile it on more than one compiler. And then also run the code through a [static analysis tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) that is dedicated to spot things that a compiler is free to ignore.

Comment: This is insanely dangerous because it gives you a false sense of security. If there is a macro called `PTR_CONST_CAST` but it actually casts everything (not just `const`ness) then there will be at some point somebody who didn't read the documentation and uses it wrongly. The only reason I'm not downvoting this is because I don't downvote competing answers (out of principle).